# DataContext - Load optional Referenced values automaticly when querying through LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have the following situation (as example)

I have a DataContext named : Master.dbml

It has 2 tables:

- Hobby {id;name;}
- HobbyReference {id;Hobby_Name;Hobby_Good_Name;}

Always when i query Hobby, the DataContext should check if (pseudo-code):

```
 Hobby.Name EXISTS in HobbyReference.Hobby_Name
 THEN 
      take HobbyReference.Hobby_Good_Name
 ELSE 
      take Hobby.Hobby_Name
 END IF
```

What's the best practice arround this?

I have an idea of how to do it (extending the datacontext), but i don't know how to fully implement it.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

`Hobby.Hobby_Name` not exists!

anyway to check before return from datacontext you can do the following:

```
public class HobbyDataService
    {
        MasterDataContext db = null;

        public HobbyDataService(string connection)
        {
            db = new MasterDataContext(connection);
        }

        internal string GetHoppyName(string hobbyName)
        {
            var x = from hr in this.db.HobbyReferences
                    where string.Equals(hr.Hoppy_Name, hobbyName)
                    select hr;
            if (x.Any())
                return x.First().Hobby_Good_Name;
            else
            {
                //Return what ever you want here
            }
        }
    }

 public partial class Hobby
    {
        public static string GetName(string hobbyName, string connection)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hobbyName))
                throw new ArgumentException("hobbyName is null or empty.", "hobbyName");
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connection))
                throw new ArgumentException("connection is null or empty.", "connection");

            HobbyDataService dataSrvce = new HobbyDataService(connection);
            return dataSrvce.GetHoppyName(hobbyName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is never more than one entry on HobbyReference for each name, and if this is used for querying (ie not for updating) then you can do something like

```
public class AmendedHobby
{
    public int Id  { get; set ;} 
    public string Name{ get; set ;} 
}

public IQueryable<AmendedHobby>  GetAmendedHobbies()
{
    return 
     (from h in Hobby
      join hr in HobbyRefernce on h.Name equals hr.Name into hrResults
      from hr in hrResults.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new { h.id , Name = hr.Hobby_Good.Name ?? r.Name}  
}
```

This should allow you to do subqueries such as

```
 (from r in GetAmendedHobbies() where r.Name == "Football" select r)
```

It will return the AmendedHobby class which, as it is not linked to an existing table, means that changes won't be persisted back to the database.